# How to make Link fit Component that its inside of it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

## What I have:

```
<div className="flexBox">
    <h4>Rampa de Cores</h4>
    <Link to={"/new"} className="link">
        <CustomButton label="Adicionar" className={"addButton"}/>
    </Link>
</div>
```

And the `<CustomButton />` returns

```
<div>
    <button className={this.props.className}>{this.props.label}</button>
</div>
```

## The Problem:

[image: buttonImage]

All the area that i marked with a red square is clickable and triggers the `<Link />` but I need to make it fit the button area only.

## What I tried:

I looked for how to make a div fit it's content, in `.link` I have

```
.link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

but didn't work.

## What i need:

1. How to make `<Link />` fit it's content?
2. Or make a better way of triggering `<Link />` using the button.

Comment: Buttons are not permitted as children of links.

Comment: You could try  `onClick` with the button.

Comment: Just replace the link with an onClick in the button. React Router provides props which will let you "push" to a new url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router provides a history prop to components.

You can replace your link and include an onClick in the button.

```
<div className="flexBox">
    <h4>Rampa de Cores</h4>
    <CustomButton 
      onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/new')} 
      label="Adicionar" 
      className={"addButton"}
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use button as a child of Link. Instead, you may use button and trigger a state change or redirection when the button is clicked. If the new route is declared with react-router-dom's Route, you may just use the following code:

```
 <div className="flexBox">
        <h4>Rampa de Cores</h4>
        <Link to={"/new"} className="link">
            <CustomButton label="Adicionar" className={"addButton"}
onButtonClick={()=>this.props.history.push('/new')}/>
        </Link>
</div>
  <button
 onClick={this.props.onButtonClick}
>{this.props.label}</button>
```

If your current component is not defined with Route, you must use `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` to get access to the history prop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below flex box styling or else simply make .link display:block; width:100%;

```
.link{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    flex-basis:50%;
    min-width:50%;
    line-height:normal;
}
```

As far as height is concerned if the parent .flexbox display property is flex then height will be picked automatically.